# Magento 2 Move Short Description below product image

Tags: magento2, page-layouts

I am new to magento2 and I have very few knowledge about it, I am using Porto theme on magento 2.3.0 CE. I am trying to move the short description under the product image.

Here is what I have :[image: Magento2 short description Default]

Here is what I want : [image: Magento2 short description Below]

I managed to get the short description under the social links by using this code :

```xml
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product-social-links"/>
```

But I don't know how to put it under the image.
Here is my catalog_product_view.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2018 Porto. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_custom_block" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product_view_custom_block"/>
        <!--<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true"/>-->
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.review"/>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_custom.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_config" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/config.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="prev_next_products" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/prev_next.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="prev_next_products" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_addthis_links" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addthis.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\RickSnippet" name="rich_snippet" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/rich_snippet.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block" ifconfig="porto_settings/product/main_custom_block" before="product.info.main" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block.phtml"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block2" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block2.phtml"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product.clearer" after="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/clearer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product_view_main_custom_block2" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
        <referenceContainer name="columns">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="side_popup" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/side_popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And this is my default.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_head" template="html/head.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="porto_newsletter_popup" template="subscribe_popup.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_notice" template="html/custom_notice.phtml" after="-"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_sidebar_sticky" template="html/sidebar_sticky.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Form\Login" name="header_customer_form_login" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/login_popup" template="Smartwave_Porto::html/login.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
                <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_block" template="html/header_custom_block.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/static_block" after="-"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="navigation.sections" destination="porto_header"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="porto_header"/>
        <move element="minicart" destination="porto_header"/>
        <move element="currency" destination="porto_header"/>
        <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
        <move element="skip_to_content" destination="porto_header"/>

        <move element="page.top" destination="page.wrapper" after="porto_header"/>

        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="1"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="1"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="1"/>

        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_link" before="authorization-link-login" template="html/custom_link.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add code in **catalog_product_view.xml** before body ends.

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.media" after="-"/>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it's almost good except that I want the short description with a 100% width so I think I need to add a new container and put the short description in it. Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: for 100% width you can update above code by:

<move element="product.info.overview" destination="content" before="product.info.details"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="content" before="product.info.details"/>
```

This will work if you want to show below media image with 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your theme catalog_product_view.xml file before `</body>` so it will so fullwidth.

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in **catalog_product_view.xml** before the body ends.

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.media"/>
```

Run comand **php bin/magento cache:flush** and check